# inf_mr does not refresh with xaringan slides

Tags: r, markdown, xaringan

When I save xaringan slides with `---` at the very beginning of the presentation, they must be removed before `xaringan::inf_mr()` will refresh the viewer panel and update changes. The following example should help create the situation:

(1) Create .Rmd file...

````
---
title: "Presentation Ninja"
date: "2016/12/12 (updated: `r Sys.Date()`)"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
     highlightStyle: github
     highlightLines: true
     countIncrementalSlides: false
---
layout: true
background-image: url(https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/releases/download/v0.0.2/karl-moustache.jpg)
background-position: 91% 94%
background-size: 185px

<!-- Must have this break below -->
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
options(htmltools.dir.version = FALSE)
```

# Test slide
Testing

---

# Test slide 2
Testing

---

# Test slide 3
Testing
````

(2) Now I run Rmd file with `xaringan::inf_mr()`... When I do this the viewer will not refresh unless I now comment/remove, without saving, the `---`:

````
---
title: "Presentation Ninja"
date: "2016/12/12 (updated: `r Sys.Date()`)"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
     highlightStyle: github
     highlightLines: true
     countIncrementalSlides: false
---
layout: true
background-image: url(https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/releases/download/v0.0.2/karl-moustache.jpg)
background-position: 91% 94%
background-size: 185px
<!-- Commented Out Now -->
<!-- --- -->

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
options(htmltools.dir.version = FALSE)
```

# Test slide
Testing

---

# Test slide 2
Testing

---

# Test slide 3
Testing
````

Now the viewer will refresh. However, every time I have to save the Rmd file, if I want the viewer to work I have to un-comment/re-comment this `---`. I must be missing something quite basic but I do not believe anyone else has reported this problem.

Here are some additional details about my system:

```
R.Version()
$`platform`
[1] "x86_64-w64-mingw32"

$arch
[1] "x86_64"

$os
[1] "mingw32"

$system
[1] "x86_64, mingw32"

$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)"

$nickname
[1] "Feather Spray"
```

-

```
rstudioapi::versionInfo()
$`mode`
[1] "desktop"

$version
[1] ‘1.2.1237’
```

My xaringan version is **0.8.15**.

If more clarity is needed just let me know.

Thank you!

**EDIT**

I added the following code to the .Rmd documents (as based on [this wiki](https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/wiki/Slide-layouts)), this should better illustrate the issue being faced:

```
layout: true
background-image: url(https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/releases/download/v0.0.2/karl-moustache.jpg)
background-position: 91% 94%
background-size: 185px
```

Comment: This sounds weird, and I couldn't reproduce it on Windows (with R 3.5.2 and [RStudio 1.2.1303](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/), although I don't think the versions of R or RStudio should matter).

Comment: @YihuiXie, thank you for the quick response. I have updated both R and RStudio to the same version as in the prior comment and the same issue seems to persist (very strange!). One additional note is that if I run `inf_mr()` on the .Rmd file without that initial `---`, it appears the second slide bumps to the first slide (i.e. the two slides merge onto one slide). The only way to correct this is to save the .Rmd with the `---`; then, if I want the autorefresh feature of `inf_mr()`, I have to comment the `---` out afterwards.

Comment: As I said, I couldn't reproduce the issue on Windows, so I cannot fix it for you, either. Unfortunately, the source code for this part is relatively complicated: https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/blob/8e06b172f65e5c9cf0b3fd4c23d7fb34c1ceab28/R/render.R#L246-L272 If you are going to debug this by yourself, it might take quite a while. The thing that I really don't understand is, as soon as you save the document, the document should be automatically recompiled and the RStudio VIewer should be refreshed. There is no reason why even this can fail.

Comment: Thank you @YihuiXie. The problem may be resolved when I remove the code at the start of the presentation (`layout: true` to `background-size: 185px`). I will take a look at the source code to see if I can find anything more specific.

Comment: FYI, [there was a bug](https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/issues/198) related to `layout: true`, which I just fixed on Github. Before you dig deeper, please try `remotes::install_github('yihui/xaringan')` again. Thanks!

Comment: @YihuiXie, I think that fixed it, thank you! (BTW, this great package has also influenced my recent Netflix playlist)

Comment: Good to know the issue was fixed! Don't waste too much time on Naruto just because of an R package name! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xaringan::inf_mr()` had [a bug](https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/issues/198) that prevented it from counting the number of slides correctly (not taking `layout: true` into consideration). I have [fixed it on Github](https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/commit/ca5d8217a042b1edd7bed822d3c40e7638941d54), and you can install the development version via:

```r
remotes::install_github('yihui/xaringan')
```